# Question about stating propositions in mathematical induction problems.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-verification, proof-writing, induction

Assume I have a proposition $P(n)$, which states "For a natural number $n$, $n = a + b$ for some natural numbers $a,b$." If I want to prove this proposition only for $n \geq c$, where $c$ is some natural number, should I change my proposition to be "For a natural number $n \geq c$, $n = a + b$", or can I just leave it like so?

Comment: You are using the same symbol $a$ to mean two different things.

Comment: Fixed it! Sorry about the confusion

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to change it because your original proposition has no restrictions on a. This would also change your induction hypothesis, as well as your proof.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake and used $a$ for two different things. Fixed now!

Answer (score 0):

It depends. It is *sufficient* to show $P(n)$ is true to infer $P_c(n),$ (which I denote to mean your changed proposition) because $P(n)$ is obviously stronger (more general) than $P_c(n)$. That means $P(n)\Rightarrow P_c(n)$ as a "byproduct", so to speak. However, depending on whether your definition of $\mathbb N$ includes or excludes $0$, you will find that $P(n)$ might be false, whereas $P_c(n)$ is true for all $c>1.$